# how to group data and calculating a specific task

Tags: python, pandas, csv, group-by, pivot-table

I have a practice task below:

Calculate the total births over the sample period by grouping the data by name and sex. Subset the group into male and female. Using these subsets, select the top and bottom 3 male and female names. Report them in a single table.

So I have a .csv file ([1]) containing names, sex, births, and year. I can't seem to figure out exactly how to do this task.

Output: [2]

```
              births
sex year            
F   1990  124.598148
    1991  121.215316
    1992  118.106646
    1993  114.475367
    1994  113.331661
    1995  111.563710
    1996  110.258765
    1997  107.671846
    1998  106.412899
    1999  104.643578
    2000  102.779761
    2001  100.116023
    2002   99.283904
    2003   99.055598
    2004   97.443251
    2005   96.216343
    2006   94.690833
    2007   93.415595
    2008   92.263176
    2009   90.823585
M   1990  216.417422
    1991  209.419977
    1992  203.524373
    1993  192.999015
    1994  188.475200
    1995  184.294158
    1996  179.760661
    1997  174.291755
    1998  169.057720
    1999  165.296596
    2000  162.003634
    2001  157.905281
    2002  155.438592
    2003  154.773933
    2004  150.038389
    2005  149.376874
    2006  146.330312
    2007  144.067535
    2008  139.294722
    2009  136.291111
```

Comment: Snippet of input data and expected output data is needed to help you.

Comment: Done! not sure exactly what the output has to look like. I just need to follow the given instructions

Comment: Please provide the snippet of data as text & not a pictures. We cannot create dataframes with pictures.

Comment: Done! sorry for that

Comment: Do you want to know the  top and bottom 3 male and female names for every year or for the whole dataset that you have?

Comment: Thank you SH-SF for helping!!

Comment: Could you possibly help me with some other tasks?
Task 1: Create a pivot table of total births by sex and year and then plot them.

Comment: Task 3: Using the top male and female names (two names in total), check their trends over time, i.e. plot the total births with these name from 1990 to 2010. In order to do this, you would first need to create a pivot table.

Comment: please ask additional questions. Trust me there are people who can make magic with Pandas & they are eager to help. Just make sure you put your input & output clearly in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, this is what you need.

```
g=g=df.groupby(['name','sex'])['births'].sum().reset_index(name='birth_sum').sort_values('birth_sum',ascending=False)
top_names=g.loc[g.sex=='F'].head(3).append(g.loc[g.sex=='M'].head(3))
bottom_names=g.loc[g.sex=='F'].tail(3).append(g.loc[g.sex=='M'].tail(3))
```

**Input** (I modified the data since the data you posted has data only for one year)

```
       name     sex births  year
0   Jessica     F   46459   1990
1   Ashley      F   45544   1990
2   Brittany    F   36532   1990
3   Amanda      F   34391   1990
4   Samantha    F   25864   1990
5   Jessica     F   46459   1991
6   Ashley      F   45544   1991
7   Brittany    F   36532   1991
8   Amanda      F   34391   1991
9   Samantha    F   55864   1991
10  Jessica     F   46459   1992
11  Ashley      F   45544   1992
12  Brittany    F   86532   1992
13  Amanda      F   34391   1992
14  Samantha    F   55864   1992
15  James       M   15      1990
16  Rob         M   20      1990
17  Bob         M   25      1990
18  Sam         M   45      1990
19  Richard     M   60      1990
20  James       M   15      1991
21  Rob         M   200     1991
22  Bob         M   300     1991
23  Sam         M   45      1991
24  Richard     M   60      1991
25  James       M   145     1992
26  Rob         M   182     1992
27  Bob         M   400     1992
28  Sam         M   216     1992
29  Richard     M   60      1992
```

**Output**

```
print(top_names)
      name     sex  birth_sum
3   Brittany    F   159596
5   Jessica     F   139377
9   Samantha    F   137592
2   Bob         M   725
7   Rob         M   402
8   Sam         M   306

print(bottom_names)
       name     sex birth_sum
9   Samantha    F   137592
1   Ashley      F   136632
0   Amanda      F   103173
8   Sam         M   306
6   Richard     M   180
4   James       M   175
```

Comment: @xching I have updated the 1st line of the code so that that output matches the names (earlier it was inverse).